# about power series for iterated logarithms

Tags: taylor-series

The question is motivated by  [this one.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57588/series-for-loglog-closed)  It turned out (see my comment there) that the coefficients of the Taylor series for $\log\log x$ at $x=e$ have nice combinatorial description from [Sloane's encyclopedia](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C-2%2C7%2C-35%2C228%2C+1834&language=english&go=Search)  (in the encyclopedia, a related but slightly more complicated function is considered). The coefficients are (up to a power of $e$ multiplied by a factorial) permanents of some easily defined matrices. 
My question is this:

Is there a combinatorial (possibly 3-dimensional) description of coefficients of the Taylor series of $\log\log\log x$ at $e^e$? Same question for $\log\log\log\log x$, etc.

Comment: Couldn't edit to correct spelling - it's "Sloane's encyclopedia" (N.J.A.Sloane)

Comment: @Gottfried: OK, thanks. I fixed that.  

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may be simpler to deal with the Maclaurin series for the functions $\log(1-x)$, $-\log(1+\log(1-x))$, $-\log(1+\log(1+\log(1-x)))$, etc. The third one, for example, is the exponential generating function for $1,3,15,105,947,10472,137337,\dots$ which is http://oeis.org/A000268 and there are a couple of references there which may be worth tracking down, J. Ginsburg, Iterated exponentials, Scripta Math., 11 (1945), 340-353 and P. J. Cameron, Sequences realized by oligomorphic permutation groups, J. Integ. Seqs. Vol. 3 (2000), #00.1.5 (and a couple of others, besides).

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be related to A039815 which is a 3-dimensional object. Still it is not a "permanent" of any 3-dimensional matrix yet. Perhaps there exists such a thing. 